# What does the main Chrome process use so much memory for?

Tags: google-chrome, memory

For me as a user, Chrome's main process ("Browser") seems quite useless and since it is taking more than 1 GB, that is almost 10%, of my RAM, I am interested what this RAM is used for.

[image: chrome task manager]

According to the Stats for Nerds it is all private memory:
[image: stats for nerds]

Comment: capture the grow of the mmeory usage with xperf and analyze it with WPA.exe: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc You must select the Chrome symbols to get the correct stacks: https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/

Comment: @magicandre1981 As a matter of fact your comment is a proper answer to my question... mind making it one?

Comment: ok, I did this. Were you able to see why Chrome uses so much RAM?

Comment: Not yet, I just restarted it and the memory usage is still reasonable. But I ran your method and have hope to see something helpful when it happens again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't know what Chrome is doing. But you can capture the memory allocations with xperf from the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) by running this cmd file:

```
@echo off
echo Press a key when ready to start...
pause

echo .
echo ...Capturing...
echo .

xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+VIRT_ALLOC -stackwalk VirtualAlloc+VirtualFree -BufferSize 1024 -MinBuffers 256 -MaxBuffers 256 -MaxFile 256 -FileMode Circular

echo Press a key when you want to stop...
pause
echo .
echo ...Stopping...
echo .

xperf -stop -d virtualalloc.etl
```

and opening it inside [Windows Performance analyzer](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-49-WPT-Memory-Analysis-VirtualAlloc) and looking at the commit stack. To get good stacks for Chrome, you have to point to the Chrome symbol server in the symbol path options:

```
srv*C:\symbols\chrome*http://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com;
```